# How to change uploaded file names to have a sequential number name not random

Tags: php, file, upload

I have an uploader on my website and it renames the image files with ("original name" + "random number") a random number at the end.

I would like to have the  uploaded files to be in a sequential order so the must recent uploaded pictures are at the top of an auto populate page.

Right now the code has random number generator and it then takes the original file name and puts its at the beginning..

I just want all pictures to read like 10.jpg then the next photo uploaded be 9.jpg and 8.jpg

the auto populate feature i have now put the smallest numbers first on page

How can this be done. my concern is that when the next person upload it will over right the previous "starting" point 10.jpg file?

You can view the php file here `http://ilovesmallies.com/forum/processupload.php`

```
 // Random number for both file, will be added after image name
    $RandomNumber   = rand(0, 9999999999); 


//Get file extension from Image name, this will be re-added after random name
    $ImageExt = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
    $ImageExt = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
```

**EDIT: All filed are upload to a directoryfolder. 
I'm using this code on a seperate page to draw them into a div. which then auto populates the thumbnails on that page.**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: "user-uploads-thumbnails",
  success: function(data){
     $(data).find("a:contains(.jpg)").each(function(){
        // will loop through 
var images = 'user-uploads-thumbnails/' + $(this).attr("href");
var linkimage = 'user-uploads/' + $(this).attr("href");
 //backup $('<p><a href="' + linkimage + '"><img src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
$('<p><a class="fancybox" href="' + linkimage + '" data-fancybox-group="gallery"><img src="' + images + '"></a></p>').appendTo('#content');
     });
  }
});
```

Comment: One safe way to do it is use a database to generate the ID and then rename the image.

Comment: Well, do you have a counter or something to keep track of how many files have been uploaded? Second, there are ways to sort files based on creation time and it does not depend on filenames. Is such a solution acceptable?

Comment: I don't care which way its done, i just want to make sure the most recent pictures are at the top...

Comment: I'm agree with @SalmanA, however if you want sort files based on their names, you can prepend `time()` to filenames.

Comment: What code does your auto populate page use? It can be modified to read files in certain order.

Comment: I edited the original post. please see the code there...

Answer (score 0):

This is a REALLY SIMPLE way of doing it. Provided no two people upload at the exact same time....

You will need to create a directory containing:

- index.php
- anotherpage.php // this name doesnt matter ( this is just to grab the most recent image
- /upload
- count.txt
- inc.php

index.php

```
<?php


    include("inc.php");
    if(isset($_FILES["file"])){
        $new_filename = read_file($counter_file); // fetch the number for filename
        $new_filename++; // increment the counter
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $new_filename.".jpg"); // assumes jpg (easily extended to other formats)
        write_to_file($new_filename,$counter_file);

        echo "<img src=\"upload/".$new_filename.".jpg\" /><br />";
    }

?>

<form id="upload" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"> 
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />  
</form>
```

anotherpage.php

```
<?php

    include("inc.php");

    $new_filename = read_file($counter_file);
    echo "<img src=\"upload/".$new_filename.".jpg\" /><br />";

?>
```

inc.php

```
<?php

        $counter_file = "count.txt"; // name of the file containing your file count

        function write_to_file($text,$filename){
            $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
            fwrite($fp, $text);
            fclose($fp);
        }

        function read_file($filename){
        $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
        fclose($handle);
        return($contents);
        }

?>
```

WARNING: this contains NO VALIDATION. Remember the mime type of a file can be spoffed. This is a simple working solution to your issue.